# How to use bounded vector for storage

Tags: storage

I'm trying to use BoundedVec from `frame_support` for one of my storage items like this,

```rust
pub(super) type Payloads<T: Config> = StorageMap<_, Blake2_128Concat, T::BlockNumber, Vec<Payload>, ValueQuery>;
```

However I'm confused how to implement `BoundedVec` here instead of `Vec` as I tried something like this which failed

```rust
pub(super) type Payloads<T: Config> = StorageMap<_, Blake2_128Concat, T::BlockNumber, BoundedVec<Payload, 100>, ValueQuery>;
```

Giving me the error,
`error[E0747]: constant provided when a type was expected`

Can someone who has already worked on this, give me an example of how to use `BoundedVec`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Having a look at the [pallet-preimage](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/f318350b6410ef47e438aae24c0b4779373d0a7b/frame/preimage/src/lib.rs#L139) shows how it can be done, the Substrate repo contains examples almost anything that you would want to do with it .

The storage item:

```rust
/// The preimages stored by this pallet.
#[pallet::storage]
pub(super) type PreimageFor<T: Config> =
    StorageMap<_, Identity, T::Hash, BoundedVec<u8, T::MaxSize>>;
```

The config which defines the `MaxSize` type:

```rust
#[pallet::config]
pub trait Config: frame_system::Config {
    /// Max size allowed for a preimage.
    type MaxSize: Get<u32>;
}
```

And the runtime where the concrete value is injected:

```rust
parameter_types! {
    pub const PreimageMaxSize: u32 = 4096 * 1024;
}

impl pallet_preimage::Config for Runtime {
    type MaxSize = PreimageMaxSize;
}
```

Comment: type MaxSize: Get<u16> cannot work. only Get<u32> works. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

`BoundedVec` is defined [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/c6aa3209d6277b853f5eb15d74fb9812024ef23c/frame/support/src/storage/bounded_vec.rs#L33) in the Substrate code base as below:

```rust
#[derive(Encode, scale_info::TypeInfo)]
#[scale_info(skip_type_params(S))]
pub struct BoundedVec<T, S>(Vec<T>, PhantomData<S>);
```

As the compiler message shows, it's expecting a type for the second generic parameter. You can use it as `BoundedVec<Payload, ConstU32<100>>` as you can also find in the `BoundedVec` [tests](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/c6aa3209d6277b853f5eb15d74fb9812024ef23c/frame/support/src/storage/bounded_vec.rs#L586), which would make your type declaration:

```rust
pub(super) type Payloads<T: Config> = StorageMap<_, Blake2_128Concat, T::BlockNumber, BoundedVec<Payload, ConstU32<100>>, ValueQuery>;
```

Comment: Ah yes the error makes sense now: use type `ConstU32<100>` rather than the constant value `100`.

Comment: ConstU16<100> cannot do. Only ConstU32<100> works. Thanks