# How to iterate over a vector in ink smart contract

Tags: ink, smart-contract

I initialized a vector in ink smart contract like this:

```
bidders: Vec<AccountId>
```

What is the best way to iterate over the vector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see examples in the docs: [ink_prelude::vec::Vec](https://docs.rs/ink_prelude/latest/ink_prelude/vec/struct.Vec.html)

```rs
for bidder in &bidders {
    // do whatever with the AccountId
}
```

Vec support indexing Vectors also support [indexing](https://docs.rs/ink_prelude/latest/ink_prelude/vec/struct.Vec.html#indexing) if you know where is the element you want to get:  `println!("{}", bidders[1]);`

And iterator (See [docs](https://docs.rs/ink_prelude/latest/ink_prelude/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.iter)):

```rs
let mut iterator = bidders.iter();
```

If you want to bound the length of a Vec in ink!, you can check this previous StackExchange response: [BoundedVec on ink!](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/7562/boundedvec-on-ink)